# AngularJS select ng-model value not in scope

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs

I am using plain options for select tag as i have to display few options only when they satisfy a condition. I need the value of the selected dropdown in controller to perform other opeartions, but the problem is i dont get the value in scope.`

```
<select id="selectView" ng-model="selectedView" ng-init="selectedView='plain'" ng-change=resultViewChanged()>
  <option value="plain" >Plain</option>
  <option value="grid" ng-if="user.gridView" >Grid</option>
  <option value="box" ng-if="user.boxView">Box</option>
</select>`
```

For now, in the controller i am just trying to get the value of selectedView. I am changing dropdown to grid and I tried below two alert's and both does not give the value grid in the alert box. How to get the value of the selected option in controller?

```
$scope.resultViewChanged = function() {
        alert($scope.selectedView.value); //Tried this undefined
        alert($scope.selectedView);
```

}

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

The selected value should be store in the $scope.selectedView (without the .value after) variable as it is defined in the ng-model.

So , this:

```
alert($scope.selectedView);
```

should alert the selected value in the dropdown.

Comment: This did not work. I am getting undefined, but when i tried @WhiteHat's solution by getting the elementById it worked. Still wondering why outputting $scope.selectedView does not work

Comment: I did a look-alike jsfiddle example, and it worked, that's strange. Here: https://jsfiddle.net/6g50497q/2/

Comment: What i have is something like this, https://jsfiddle.net/8dh3LzLd/ . This does not seem to work, i wonder what am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

how 'bout this?

```
alert(document.getElementById('selectView').value);
```

Comment: This did work, but i am wondering why alert($scope.selectedView); does not work?

Comment: sorry, never used Angular but I know JS